# How do i get the response HTML of an entire Page from a Cucumber Step that uses Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, bdd

When running my specs i get errors where Capybara couldn't find elements based on their labels and such. Then i thought i wanted the HTML, or somehow debug the errors.

This is the /features/merge.feature

```
#Just a test!
Scenario: Cannot merge articles when not admin
    Given I am not an admin
    When I am on the edit article page
    Then I should not see the "merge articles" form
```

And this is: /feature/step_definitions/merge.rb - and it only contains "Given" statements!

```
Given /am not an admin$/ do
  visit '/accounts/login'
  puts "TEZT"
  puts page.native
  puts page.native.text
  fill_in 'user_login', :with => 'editor_rico'
  fill_in 'user_password', :with => 'a'
  click_button 'Login'
end

Given /^I am an admin$/ do
  visit '/accounts/login'
  fill_in 'user_login', :with => 'admin_rico'
  fill_in 'user_password', :with => 'a'
  click_button 'Login'
end
```

Then i get this error:

```
Scenario: Cannot merge articles when not admin    
# features/article_merging.feature:20
Given I am not an admin                 
#features/step_definitions/article_steps.rb:39
cannot fill in, no text field, text area or password field with id, name, or label
'user_login' found (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
(eval):2:in `fill_in'
./features/step_definitions/article_steps.rb:44:in `/am not an admin$/'
features/article_merging.feature:21:in `Given I am not an admin'
```

Havin a rough time working with Cucumber here ..

1) Why do i get the above

2) How do i debug it, i wanna see the HTML code!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This errors appears when your page HTML does not contain any `input` or `textarea` element with name, id or label `'user_login'`. If you add the `launchy` gem to your Gemfile you will be able to see how your page looks:

In your `Gemfile`:

```
group :test do
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'capybara'
  ...
end
```

Then, inside your `feature/step_definitions/merge.rb` file:

```
Given /^I am not an admin$/ do
  visit '/accounts/login'
  save_and_open_page
end
```

The `save_and_open_page` will open the current page in your browser, so then you can inspect the HTML and see what it looks like.

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Thank you @mrcasals - this worked perfectly. I also read somewhere you can actually do: puts page.body.

Comment: Nice tip too! But the point of using my example is that if you precompile your app assets, you will see exactly what you are reproducing with your steps (that is, with both HTML and CSS), which is always good to have :) But yeah, `puts page.body` can work too if you are in a hurry :)

Answer (score 1):

It think the issue with the above code is that 'page' doesn't become available until after you end the section.

Try putting your 'puts' into the 'When'or 'Then' step

You can query page as follows (assuming you're using RSpec)

```
page.should have_content 'foo'
page.should have_selector 'h1', text: => 'Hello dave'
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I edited the question @muttonlamb  please see it again because i didn't understand this answer. I'm using Cucumber, and working step definitions. I read in the Documentation that there *might* be something called Page. I'm not sure.

Comment: Seems like capybara is not finding the elements on the page, have you tried opening the page in your browser normally?  You can then inspect the HTML and work out of the naming of your field is correct.

The suggestion below about using launchy is also a good one

Comment: this also helped with the should assertion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also see the HTML response by printing `page.body` to stdout.

```
Given /^I am not an admin$/ do
  visit '/accounts/login'
  puts page.body
end
```